# How to use variable to help pick member of struct to utilize

Tags: c++, variables, input, struct

In the program I am writing I have various structs with several members. Saved in several string I have different members of the structs names. How do I use those strings to choose the data from the member I want?

Example:

```
struct teams
{ double x;
  double y;
};

teams cardinals = {1, 2};
teams pirates = {};
teams cubs = {};

team1 = "cardinals";
```

I want to do the equivalent of outputting team1.x but I have no idea how. Help?

Comment: In your code, `team1` is `std::string` or `char*`.  You can't access `teams` member variables on types that aren't `teams`.

Comment: You might want to add the team name to your struct (also, why doubles when you assign integers?). Then put the teams into a container, like `std::map` (direct access via name) or `std::vector` (use `find` functions).

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a strongly typed language, so you really can't achieve this. There are languages like ruby which give you the feature of converting a symbol to a string and vice-versa.

As I understand your questions, What you probably are asking is to associate names for selecting structures. Based on this understanding, you could create enum, declare vector or array of structs and then use them

```
enum {CARDINALS=0, PIRATES, CUBS, MAX_SIZE};
struct teams
{ double x;
  double y;
};
struct teams allTeams[MAX_SIZE+1];

teams[CARDINALS] = {1,2};
```

Hope it helps!